# OOP Inheritance: Modifying Array in Base Class from Derived Class

Tags: c++, oop

I have this code:

```
class Base{
public:
 int A[3]={1,2,3};
 void out(){
    for (int i=0;i<3;++i) cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
 }  
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
 void modify(){
    A[2] = 5;
}
 };

int main(){
  Base base;
  Derived derived;
  base.out();
  derived.modify();
  base.out();
  return 0;
}

OUTPUT: 1 2 3 
        1 2 3
```

What I'm trying to do is to modify A[2] and print the array with the changed value through function in Base class.
But the problem is after I modify it in my Derived class and print the array with the function in my Base class, it's still the old array from the Base function.

Comment: `base` and `derived` are two completely separate objects that are not connected in any way. `derived.modify()` modifies its own copy of `A`, not that of `base`

Comment: You have two different objects. You output the info of one object and then modify the other and then print the first one again.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood inheritance.

Comment: Try `derived.out()`.

Comment: If it is desired to share A between all instances A array should be static member in base class.

Comment: I think you haven't completely understood the difference between classes (which are types, not things) and objects (which are things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because base and derived are completely different copies of objects, so modifying in one doesn't reflect on the other. So you have to use derived.out(); to get the modified array. But uncommenting either of the comments down here works if you want to modify through base class object.

```
int main()
{
  Base base;
  Derived derived;
  base.out();
  derived.modify();
  derived.out();
  //base.A[2]=5;
  //base=derived;
  base.out();
  return 0;
}
```